# How change in magnetic field induces emf in conductors?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

Some conductors have internal magnetic field that opposes the external field so how does emf will induce in it like copper is dimagnetic but how emf induce in it.

Similarly how emf induces on other conductors.
That arises a question why induce emf as per faraday law is independant to material own charecterstics why????

Answer (score -1):

A moving magnetic field will create eddy currents in a conductor. eddy currents are the whirlpool currents like we see in streams. As we know magnetic fields can create electric currents and vis versa. We also know that when electrons flow there is a electromagnetic field that is created. So if the magnetic field creates an eddy current it creates a electromagnetic field, which will then oppose the magnetic field that created the eddy current. I think...